# Database Pentest methodology or list?

Tags: penetration-test, databases

I am looking for a practical database pentest methodology (database level test). I checked the Internet but there is no much info. Where I should start and on which areas (step by step) should I focus when I define the scope?

Comment: Voting to close this because it is too broad. There are different methods for different database solutions. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Following could be the high level steps in Penetration Test of DB level:

• Information Gathering

• Enumeration

• SQL Injection in MSSQL

• Injection in Stored Procedures

• SYSTEM Level Attack

• Exploiting Known MySQL Issues

• Hash Cracking

• TNS Listener

• PL/SQL Injection

• Authentication/Authorization vulnerability

Further you may refer below link for the detail technical details of DB level pen test:

http://www.spy-hunter.com/Database_Pen_Testing_ISSA_March_25_V2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll get a satisfying answer, largely because a lot of pentesting is experience: poking around the system and saying "hmm, it looks like they... I wonder if ...". Ultimately, to do a good job at pentisthing, you need to be very familiar with the technologies involved.

When I'm testing a technology that I'm not very familiar with, I often start by reading the OWASP testing guides and then google dive on any terms or concepts that I'm not familiar with. For DBs:

- [OWASP Backend Security Project DB Testing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Backend_Security_Project_DB_Testing) goes through some examples of an intentionally vulnerable backend.
- [OWASP Backend Security Project SQLServer Hardening](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Backend_Security_Project_SQLServer_Hardening) is a guide for hardening a DB server. While not directly a pentesting guide, it'll give you ideas for where to poke.
- Finally, there's the [OWASP Application Security Verification Standard](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_Project) which, while while there's no database-specific section, will cover all the important points directly or indirectly.